# range based for loop with const shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, pointers, iteration, constants, container-data-type

I have a container with `shared_ptr<>`, e.g. a `vector<shared_ptr<string>>` `v` and I'd like to iterate over `v` indicating const-ness.

This code:

```
vector<shared_ptr<string>> v;
v.push_back(make_shared<std::string>("hallo"));
...

for (const auto &s : v) {
    *s += ".";   // <<== should be invalid
}
```

*looks* like what I want to do (indicating that `s` is `const`) but of course it does not make the string `const`.

Is there an elegant way to iterate over a container of `shared_ptr` which makes clear that the content won't be modified?

Something like

```
for (shared_ptr<const string> s : v) {
    *s += ".";   // <<== will not compile
}
```

(but this code would not compile for other reasons :))

**Edit:**

I made a mistake. Originally I was declaring a reference, which results in a compiler error

```
for (shared_ptr<const string> &s : v) {   // <<== does not compile
    ...
}
```

If you declare a `shared_ptr<const string>` the example works. In my eyes this is a good trade-off but this way the pointer gets copied which can be time consuming in loops with little code and big containers..

Comment: What's the problem with `for (shared_ptr<const string> s : v) { *s += "."; }`?

Comment: Seems to me your *Something like* example is exactly what you need, so what's your question?

Comment: @cpplearner It doesn't work, is the main flaw.

Comment: @Lightness The first example says `*s += "."; // <<== should be invalid` and that's exactly what the second example achieves, it makes `s` point to a `const string`. Is that not what he's looking for?

Comment: I get a `main.cpp:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::shared_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> >&' from expression of type 'std::shared_ptr<std::basic_string<char> >'` error in the `for()` line - but I see the problem: I've been declaring a **reference**: `shared_ptr<const string> &s`

Comment: It'll work even if you write `for (shared_ptr<const string> const& s : v) { ... }` but in either case you'll be constructing a `shared_ptr<const string>`. There's no way around that because you have a different type of `shared_ptr` to begin with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a well-known limitation of C++ that some don't consider to be a limitation.

You want to iterate `const`ly, but an immutable pointer doesn't imply an immutable pointee.

The type `shared_ptr<string>` and the type `shared_ptr<const string>` are effectively unrelated.

#### Option 1

```
for (const auto& ptr : v) {
    const auto& s = *ptr;

    s += ".";   // <<== is invalid
}
```

#### Option 2

Just don't modify it.

Comment: The types aren't quite as unrelated as you make it sound, though. If you really wanted, you could write: `for (const auto& p : std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>>(v.begin(), v.end()) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @KerrekSB: There exists a conversion path between them, sure. Just as you can convert from `int` to `float`. But the two are still distinct types, and the distinction goes beyond cv-qualification. Just as here.

Comment: if `ptr` is empty, wouldn't it cause undefined behaviour?

Comment: Since there seems to be no single statement approach without copying the pointer your option 1 seems to be closest to what I'm looking for. So I make this the answer. The two statements and the risk David is pointing out leave a bad taste though..

Comment: @DavidHaim: Yes but no more so than in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer.

But first, the sermon:

A pointer and the thing it points to are two separate objects. Either, none or both may be const and a const pointer simply means that it will not point to a different thing. If the pointee is const, the object may not be changed through the (possibly non-const) pointer.

Having said that, we (I) often write value-semantic wrapper objects that use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` as the pimpl. Often we wish to propogate the constness of the wrapper to impl.

I believe c++17 will solve this with it's `propagate_const` pointer wrapper.

In the meantime it's straightforward to build your own:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace traits
{
    template<class T> struct pointee;
    template<class T, class D>
    struct pointee<std::unique_ptr<T, D>> {
        using type = T;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct pointee<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
        using type = T;
    };

    template<class T> using pointee_t = typename pointee<T>::type;
}

template<class PointerType>
struct propagate_const
{
    using pointer_type = PointerType;
    using element_type = traits::pointee_t<pointer_type>;
    using value_type = std::decay_t<element_type>;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;

    propagate_const(pointer_type p) : _ptr(std::move(p)) {}

    const_reference operator*() const {
        return *_ptr;
    }

    auto operator*()
    -> std::enable_if_t<not std::is_const<element_type>::value, reference>
    {
        return *_ptr;
    }

private:
    pointer_type _ptr;
};

template<class PointerType>
auto make_propagating_pointer(PointerType&& p)
{
    return propagate_const<PointerType>(std::forward<PointerType>(p));
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<propagate_const<shared_ptr<string>>> v;
    v.emplace_back(make_shared<string>("hello"));

    for (const auto& p : v)
    {
//        *p += " there";  // compile error
        cout << *p;
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (auto& p : v)
    {
        *p += " there";
        cout << *p;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
hello
hello there
```

This one is very simple, supporting only `operator*` but it's trivial to add a complete set of operators. Note that I disable mutable access when the pointee is const.

reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const

And just for fun, here's a complete example of a `shared_string` class that uses `shared_ptr` internally and propagates constness correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class PointerType>
struct propagate_const
{
    using pointer_type = PointerType;
    using element_type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<PointerType&>())>;
    using reference = element_type&;
    using const_reference = const element_type&;

    propagate_const(pointer_type p) : _ptr(std::move(p)) {}

    const_reference operator*() const {
        return *_ptr;
    }

    auto operator*()
    -> std::enable_if_t<not std::is_const<element_type>::value, reference>
    {
        return *_ptr;
    }

private:
    pointer_type _ptr;
};

template<class PointerType>
auto make_propagating_pointer(PointerType&& p)
{
    return propagate_const<PointerType>(std::forward<PointerType>(p));
}

struct shared_string
{
    shared_string(std::string s) : _impl(std::make_shared<std::string>(std::move(s))) {};
    shared_string(std::shared_ptr<std::string> sp) : _impl(sp) {};
    shared_string(propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> sp) : _impl(sp) {};

    auto& operator += (const std::string& s) {
        *_impl += s;
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const shared_string& ss) {
        return os << *(ss._impl);
    }

private:
    propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> _impl;
};

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<T>::value>* = nullptr >
std::string check_const(T&)
{
    return std::string("const");
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<not std::is_const<T>::value>* = nullptr >
std::string check_const(T&)
{
    return std::string("not const");
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // a vector of mutable shared_strings
    vector<shared_string> v;

    // a vector of immutable shared_strings
    vector<const shared_string> cv;

    // make a shared_string
    v.emplace_back(make_shared<string>("hello"));

    // refer to the *same one* in cv
    cv.emplace_back(v[0]);

    for (const auto& p : v)
    {
//        *p += " there";  // immutable reference to mutable shared string - not allowed
        cout << check_const(p) << " " << p;
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (auto& p : v)
    {
        cout << check_const(p) << " " << p;
        p += " there";    // mutable reference to mutable shared string - allowed
        cout << " becomes " << p;
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (auto&p : cv)
    {
        cout << check_const(p) << " " << p;
//        p += " world";     // p is actually immutable because cv contains immutable objects
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
const hello
not const hello becomes hello there
const hello there
```

Comment: +1 for the `propagate_const` hint but your answer seems a bit verbose to me. For bigger APIs this might be an approach though..

Comment: @frans thank you. One never knows how far to go with an answer, so just in case someone else asks the same question I like to offer an expanded answer in case people are interested.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with template approarch

```
template <class T,class F>
void forEach(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>& vec, F&& f){
  for (const auto& ptr : vec){
      if (ptr){
         f(std::cref(*ptr));
     }
  }
}
```

I you put a lambda function there, the compiler will probably inline it anyway, so no performance damage here.