# How to prevent non-const pointer modifications through a const class interface

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Example code:

```
class Foo
{
  void m();
}

class Bar
{
  void m() const
  {
    fooPtr->m();   // allowed    
    // foo.m();    // disallowed at compile-time as I wish
  }

private:
  Foo* fooPtr;
  Foo foo;
}
```

The following client code might now change the inner data of my object even though intuitively I expect it not to:

```
int main()
{
  const Bar bar;
  bar.m();
}
```

An improvement could be made by introducing accessor methods like this:

```
class Bar
{
  Foo* foo()             { return foo; }
  const Foo* foo() const { return foo; }

  void m() const
  {
    foo()->m();
  }
private:
  Foo* foo;
}
```

However, accessing foo directly from within Bar is still valid and no compiler error, so developers might still do it and circumvent the object's constness. Another problem is that I will produce large diffs if I have to change foo's access in the entire class. Is there a nicer solution for this issue?

Comment: See [propagate_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const). Found a barebones implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34516631/2491746).

Comment: Personally, I don't think there is much use in putting effort to ensure the member variables will not be misused from INSIDE the class. We usually just make all possible for the users of the class cannot misuse it from OUTSIDE. Also its important to keep interface minimal. So, I would not add foo()'s methods if no outer classes need them.